# Remove particular string from url Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, explode

I need to remove size i.e. resolution of image path from url. Take following example:

```
http://raudevlocal.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/0000362_chocolate-layer-cake-1024x682.jpeg
```

I need to remove -1024x682

```
http://raudevlocal.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/rohit-300x118.jpg
```

Need to remove -300x118

Comment: A quick suggestion `/(-\d{2,6}x\d{2,6}).\w{3,4}$/`. It's not complete, but it may help

Comment: It would be much more effective to change it on the server via routing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use regular expression

```js
var string = "http://raudevlocal.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/0000362_chocolate-layer-cake-1024x682.jpeg";

console.log(string.replace(/-\d+x\d+/g,''));

window.loaction.href= window.location.href.replace(/-\d+x\d+/g,'');
```

Comment: last line is your answer. i didn't add that line that's why -1. after -1 i edited my answer

Comment: no, this is my answer : `console.log(string.replace(/-\d+x\d+/g,''));`

Answer (score 0):

use regex pattern

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/(-\d{2-6}x\d{2-6})/g,'');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "http://raudevlocal.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/0000362_chocolate-layer-cake-1024x682.jpeg";
str.replace(/-(\d+x\d+)/, "");
output will be
http://raudevlocal.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/0000362_chocolate-layer-cake.jpeg
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `replace` function

```
window.location.href.replace('-1024x682', '');
```

If you want to use the new one as your current url then try

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('-1024x682', '');
```

Comment: `replcae` -> `replace`

Comment: How can I know the position of this string, each time it will be different

Comment: This isn't a very robust solution as it relies on the image size being the same every time. Once that changes the above will have to be edited manually. A regex would be more suitable due to scalability and lower manual maintenance.